# Is there a way to conditionally delete columns in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a large spreadsheet with hundreds of columns. About half of the column headings have the word "alone" in them. I need to delete all of the columns that contain "alone" in the header row. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you will share a link to the sheet here, being sure to set permission as "Anyone with the link can Edit" (not just "... can View"), I or someone else here can help you. In my thinking, you don't need a script. I could accomplish this in about two minutes, if I had access to the sheet (while explaining how would take 20 times as long).

Comment: I've genericized the question to make it about the problem to be solved, rather than how to find a pre-selected solution.

Answer (score 0):

no. however,

you can take it from the other end and create a sheet with a query that will exclude all "alone" columns like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TO_TEXT(A1:D));"select * where Col1 <>'alone' 
                                                                   and Col2 <>'alone' 
                                                                   and Col3 <>'alone'
                                                                   and Col4 <>'alone'")))
```


etc...

Comment: Why would you rollback that edit? Non-standard capitalization and punctuation makes posts harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, actually there are several ways. Maybe the simplest is by using Google Apps Script and a JavaScript's `for` and if `statements`.

Here is an example of a basic script (untested) that will, on the active sheet, loop backward looking for cells on the first row (*headers*) having `alone` as value, if this occurs, then it will delete the column otherwise will pass to the next *header*.

```
function deleteAloneColumns(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastColumnPos = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var headers = sheet.getRange( 1 ,1, 1, lastColumnPos ).getValues()[0];
  for( var i = lastColumnPos ; i < 1; i--){
    if( headers[i] === "alone" ) sheet.deleteColumn(i);
  }
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert( 'Job done!' );
}
```

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets